# What is different between "fall asleep" and "go asleep"?

Tags: phrase-usage

What is different between "fall asleep" and "go asleep"?

A native friend of mine said especially "go asleep" has a nuance like ZZZZZ~~~.

Meanwhile I googled the image about "go asleep". But it looks alike to me.

What is different between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience of US English, "go asleep" is essentially never used. Nor have I encountered it in my reading of UK, Canadian, Australian or Indian English. I suspect it would be seen by most native speakers as meaning "fall asleep" but as being odd. It might be a regional or dialectical usage that I have not encountered. I would advise against using it.

"Fall asleep" is a very common usage indeed. It means that a person (or animal) who is awake becomes asleep. It means "go to sleep".  It is a phrase with a very long history.